# Install JMF in silent mode via C#

Tags: c#, jmf, silent

Is there any way to install JMF in silent mode using C#?

I have jmf.iss and JMF setup.exe and I'm having problems setting the silent parameter:

```
        string[] programArray = {"SETUP.exe","Java-jre-7u45-windows-i586"};
        foreach (string path in programArray)
        {

                using (Process p = new Process())
                {
                    string arg = "passive";


                    if (path.Contains("SETUP"))
                    {

                        arg = "s /f1" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"jmf.iss";
                    }



                    else if (path.Contains("Java"))
                    {
                        arg = "s";
                    }



                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + path);

                    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/" + arg, path);
                    p.Start();

                    //p.WaitForExit(); 
                    while (!p.HasExited)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }

            }
```

Comment: This isn't valid code to start an external process. Where is the code that passes the path of the executable and actually starts the process ? Are you getting an error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: You can see my code now. I editted. I am getting parameter error.

Comment: Instead of mixing up different executables and arguments, just use [Process.Start(string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) to start one program at a time with its proper arguments.